# how to write a data from vector to a text file at a particular position using c++?

Tags: c++

If my text file looks so..

usrname@gmail.com  3223434324 data1 data2

name@gamil.com     2343454454 data3 data4

I have read these values using vector.
I need to add a string at the end of first line of the file.
What should I do? 
My code is as follows:

```
system("cls");
cout << "\nView proposal\n";
fstream file1;
string ap, aname, aphno;
file1.open("C:\\Users\\Nandhu\\Desktop\\glosys\\joinpolicy.txt",
    ios::in|ios::app);
while(!file1.eof())
{
    while(getline(file1, text))
    {
        istringstream xstream(text);
        vector<string> vcol;
        while(getline(xstream, word, ','))
        {
            vcol.push_back(word);
        }
        vec.push_back(vcol);
    }
    file1.close();
}
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator itr = vec.begin();
    itr != vec.end(); itr++)
{
    for(vector<string>::iterator itr2 = itr->begin();
        itr2 != itr->end(); itr2++)
    {
        string str;
        str = *itr2;
        cout << str << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
cout << "\n1.Approve";
cout << "\n2.Reject";
cout << "\nDo you wish to approve?";
cin >> ans;     
if(ans == 'y')
{
    file1.open("C:\\Users\\Nandhu\\Desktop\\glosys\\joinpolicy.txt",
        ios::in|ios::app);
    file1.seekg(0);
    cout << "\nEnter the customer id you wish to approve for:";
    cin >> aname;
    vec.clear();
    if(file1.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(file1, text))
        {
            istringstream xstream(text);
            vector<string> vcol;
            while(getline(xstream, word, ','))
            {
                vcol.push_back(word);
            }
            vec.push_back(vcol);
        }
        file1.close();
    }

    for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator itr = vec.begin();
        itr != vec.end(); itr++)
    {   
        vector<vector<string> > vec;
        vector<string> vcol;

        for(vector<string>::iterator itr2 = itr->begin();
            itr2 != itr->end(); itr2++)
        {
            string str;
            str=*itr2;
            if(str==aname)
            {
                itr + 3;    
                file1.open("C:\\Users\\Nandhu\\Desktop\\glosys\\joinpolicy.txt",
                    ios::out|ios::app);
                vector<string>.insert(itr->end(), "approved");
                file1 << "approved";
                cout << "approved";
                file1.close();
            }   
        }
    }
}       
break;
```

Comment: Seem to be missing some code and the formatting is all over the shop Please rectify

Comment: Please fix the formatting and indentation in the code

Comment: is my code ok now?

Comment: Nothing is going to move the data *after* your insertion-point further down the file. You have to do it , usually by rewriting the entire file from the point of your alteration through to the end. Only if you're *changing* existing content within the file *and* the old data size matches the new data size can you get away with surgical replacement. You're inserting; not changing, so a rewrite is inevitable to one degree or another.

Comment: The indentation is all over the place

Comment: You can't insert in the middle of a text file, file systems don't support that.

Comment: how do i do that...

Comment: yeah ,but i jus want the string to be inserted at the end of the corressponding data

Comment: "the string to be inserted" - As soon as you said "inserted" stop. Go back to the first sentence in my prior comment. You're inserting data into an entity that must expand to make the hole for your insertion by *you* expanding it via rewrite. An in-memory array would be no different. (except obviously easier and faster). You identify an insertion point, everything past there has to be moved to accommodate the size of the hole you need for you insertion.

Comment: This kind of problem is generally solved by having all the data in memory, and just writing it as a new file when changes need to be saved. Text editors for example work like this. If you have a lot of data, you use a database (many many different kinds exist), which solves the insertion problem via *much* more complex file structure where new data can be written at end or a new file, and still be found.

Comment: ok but i am doing dis in c++..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly insert data in the middle of a file. You can only re-write the entire file or append to it at the end.

To insert data in the middle you have a few options:

1) Read the file into a memory buffer, transform it as needed and then truncate the file to zero length and rewrite it from the buffer.

2) As 1, but instead of truncating the original file, write a new (temporary) file and then rename it over the original.

3) Identify the point where you need to make changes, read everything after that point to a memory buffer and make your changes, then truncate the file to the size previously identified and then write the memory buffer to the file in append mode.

4) Memory map the file, make the changes needed and flush them to the file.

Comment: I honestly don't have time for that right now, but at least you now know what to research.